# Passing the clicked element to a function

Tags: javascript, event-handling, this

The button 2 does not work as expected (update it's text like button 1). "this" does not refer to the button element but to window. How can I fix the button 2? thanks

```html
<button id="btn1">Click me 1</button>
<button id="btn2">Click me 2</button>

<script>
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

  btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.innerText = "Come on";
  });


  btn2.addEventListener("click", changeMyText(this));

  function changeMyText(btn) {
    btn.innerText = "Come on";
   // console.log(btn);
    //here I get the window object
    //I expected the button
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You execute the handler immediately  - remove the (this) and use e.target

Also I would change to type="button"

```html
<button type="button" id="btn1">Click me 1</button>
<button type="button" id="btn2">Click me 2</button>

<script>
  var btn1 = document.getElementById("btn1");
  var btn2 = document.getElementById("btn2");

  btn1.addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.innerText = "Come on";
  });


  btn2.addEventListener("click", changeMyText);

  function changeMyText(e) {
    e.target.innerText = "Come on";
  }
</script>
```